# php code in html email?

Tags: php, html, email

This is probably a very stupid question but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Can php code be used inside the body of a html email?

I have only every used variable names inside an email before i.e.

```
'<p>Dear'.$name.'</p>
```

But what if I want to make a table of data and use a loop? Can I put the php loop code in the email html? I have tried but it does not seem to like my syntax no matter what I try.

Just to be clear I have no problems sending the email.

Comment: Remember, PHP runs on the ***server***, *not* the client.  Here, the "client" is the email client.  PHP is used to *generate* the HTML that is emailed to the client.  If there is an issue, then it has nothing to do with the email client.  Show us your loop/table code and the *exact* error you're getting, and we can help.

Comment: Understood but wont the php run before the email is sent? How do the variables print out as html if this isnt the case?

Comment: you run the php, to create the email(html) to be sent

Comment: Can you please provide the full code so that we can see what is going wrong. What you have above will send correctly so something else is going awry.

Comment: How are you running the PHP?  You run the code, it creates an HTML string, it emails that HTML.

Comment: ok, so if I have a loop in the email the same as a variable wont this run, print out my html and send the email?

Comment: @Drdavidpier: Forget about the email for a second.  Just think about the PHP code.  All it's doing is creating an HTML string and putting that in a variable.  How are you doing that?  Once we get that working, you can email it.

Comment: You basicaly want a form letter - e.g. you don't send out a Word file that contains the `{firstname}`, `{lastname}` etc... placeholders. Word REPLACES those placeholders with the recipient's actual data as part of a mail merge, then sends out the generated document. PHP does the same thing - you provided values for those variables on the server, generate the html with the values filled in, then send out the generated html.

Comment: ah, got it. Now I feel stupid

Comment: the loop is not in the email, its in the php that creates the email

Comment: you use PHP only as a server side ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanTarekWahdan um yes? Not sure I understand the question?

Comment: I mean if you use C# or Java or whatever, you can do what you want using sessions.

Comment: Thanks. I will stick with php and put my logic outside the email.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanTarekWahdan You can do that with PHP as well, or pretty much any other server-side language.

Comment: @Drdavidpier Consider using something like Smarty and create an e-mail template that gets populated when you run your e-mail queue.

Comment: @Brad thanks for the reminder, been meaning to check this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language. You can use PHP on your server to create a HTML code for your e-mail. But you cannot include the PHP code in your email.

Example of creating a table with PHP for an email.

```
<?php
$my_data = Array(
                    Array("John", "32",  "Male"),
                    Array("Casey", "28",  "Male"),
                    Array("Peter", "43",  "Male"),
                    Array("Michael", "19",  "Male"),
                    Array("Samantha", "22",  "Female")
);


$table = "<table>";
$table .= " <tr>";
$table .= "     <td>Name</td>";
$table .= "     <td>Age</td>";
$table .= "     <td>Gender</td>";
$table .= " </tr>";
foreach($my_data AS $value)
{
    $table .="<tr>";
    $table .= " <td>".$value[0]."</td>";
    $table .= " <td>".$value[1]."</td>";
    $table .= " <td>".$value[2]."</td>";
    $table .="</tr>";
}

$table .= "</table>";

mail("info@domain.com", "Our users", $table);
?>
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer to help others so I will mark it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use php and variables to generate a custom message, using a loop, but you should then send each email as plain text or html. If you insert some php code in the content sent, the receiver will see it as plain text, it won't be executed.